# Using .replace to replace text with HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace text with an image using jQuery. I have been using the .replace function to replace text with more text. How would I replace the text with an html tag, like an <img> tag.

Here is my code:

```
function wow() {
  $('.messageBody').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      var image = '<img class = "emote" src = "trump.png">'
      $(this).text(text.replace(':trump:', image.outterHTML));
  });
}
setInterval(wow, 1000);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="messageBody">:trump:</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `.html` instead of `.text` it will work. Change this line:

```
  $(this).text(text.replace(':trump:', image.outterHTML));
```

to this:

```
  $(this).html(text.replace(':trump:', image));
```

Note: because `image` is a string you don't need the `.outerHTML`.

If the `messageBody` has more than just text inside (it contains HTML) then you'll also want to change this line:

```
  var text = $(this).text();
```

to this:

```
  var text = $(this).html();
```

so the full code would be:

```
function wow() {
  $('.messageBody').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).html();
      var image = '<img class="emote" src="trump.png">';
      $(this).html(text.replace(':trump:', image));
  });
}
setInterval(wow, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can use [`html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) which also will loop all instances

```
$('.messageBody').html(function(_, existingHtml){
    var image = '<img class = "emote" src = "trump.png">'
    return existingHtml.replace(':trump', image);
});
```

Using `text()` strips any html tags

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't understand how to get the code to loop every time another message appeared, Thanks bunches!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
function wow() {
  $('.messageBody').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      var image = '<img class = "emote" src = "trump.png">'
      $(this).html(text.replace(':trump:', image));
  });
}
setInterval(wow, 1000);
```