# Replacing text with HTML using Cheerio in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, cheerio

I want to replace all the occurrences of a word inside a structured HTML with a tag.

For example, given an HTML like this

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porttitor, magna nec sollicitudin varius, ligula nisi finibus nulla, vel posuere libero erat eu tortor.
</p>
<p>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>ipsum</li>
        <li>dolor</li>
        <li>sit</li>
        <li>amet</li>
    </ul>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem <b>ipsum</b> <span><em>dolor</em></span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

I would like to replace all the occurrences of the word 'ipsum' with this tag

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a>
```

In this case, I tried a very simple solution that did not work:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(lorem_ipsum_html);
let words = $.text().trim().split(' ');
for (let t in words) {
    let res = words[t];
    if (words[t] == 'ipsum') res = '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a>';
    $.html().replace(words[t], res);
}
return $.html();
```

In this case the function returns the unchanged html, even though the replace looked like it worked.
On top of that, I also tried to port several jQuery implementations such as:

[Replace text with HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794984/replace-text-with-html-element)

[Using .replace to replace text with HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076537/using-replace-to-replace-text-with-html)

with no luck.

Comment: [`for in` is for `object` objects. Not — for `array` objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) `split()` gives an array. Use `forEach` or `for-loop`. Or does `cheerio` put it into an `object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this (not so clean) solution. It's not the best thing in the world but it works. There's still room for improvement here.

```
let $ = cheerio.load(lorem_ipsum_html);
let words = $.text().trim().split(' ');
for (let t in words) {
    let res =  words[t];
    if(words[t] == 'ipsum') res = '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a>';
    let $ = cheerio.load($.html().replace(words[t], res));
}
return $.html();
```

In this case the HTML structure remain intact, and the anchor tags are just injected in the right place.

```html
<p>
    Lorem <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porttitor, magna nec sollicitudin varius, ligula nisi finibus nulla, vel posuere libero erat eu tortor.
</p>
<p>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a></li>
        <li>dolor</li>
        <li>sit</li>
        <li>amet</li>
    </ul>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem <b><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a></b> <span><em>dolor</em></span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

Comment: `let $ = cheerio.load(...);` inside the loop results in `Cannot access '$' before initialization` error. As a workaround, declare `let result=$.html()` before loop, then `result=result.replace(...)` inside the loop. Finally, `return result` after loop.

Answer (score 4):

**1-** Load body with cheerio

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
```

**2-** With this recursive function you can replace your target in all elements and their children

```
function replacer($, text) {
    if ($(text).children().length) {
        $(text).children().each(function (itm) {
            return replacer($, $(this));
        });
    }
    else {
        var value = $(text).text();
        value = value.replace(/ipsum/g, '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a>');
        return $(text).text(value);
    }
}
```

**3-** Turn cheerio dom nodes back to html with this

```
return $.html(bb);
```

**4-** Replace all `&quot;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;` with right symbols.

```
f(b).replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
```

I hope this helps you. Just modify where you want of code

```
var b = `<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porttitor, magna nec sollicitudin varius, ligula nisi finibus nulla, vel posuere libero erat eu tortor.
</p>
<p>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
</ul>
</p>
<p>
Lorem <b>ipsum</b> <span><em>dolor</em></span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>`;

var cheerio = require('cheerio');

function replacer($, text) {
  if ($(text).children().length) {
    $(text).children().each(function(itm) {
      return replacer($, $(this));
    });
  } else {
    var value = $(text).text();
    value = value.replace(/ipsum/g, '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a>');
    return $(text).text(value);
  }
}

function f(body) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  var bb = $("p").each(function(itm) {
    return replacer($, $(this));
  });
  return $.html(bb);
}

console.log(f(b).replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&quot;/g, '"'))
```

Output:

```html
<p>
  Lorem <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porttitor, magna nec sollicitudin varius, ligula nisi finibus nulla, vel posuere libero erat eu tortor.
</p>
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a></li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
  </ul>
</p>
<p>
  Lorem <b><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a></b> <span><em>dolor</em></span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: This is the approach that I was using previously, but the problem here is that the HTML structure is not maintained.

Comment: You mean `<b>ipsum</b>` for example??! @holographix

Comment: yep, exactly that.

Comment: I got a solution, it's kinda dirty but it works. gonna post it in a sec

Comment: Yes, I saw it. This code also is another solution for your example provided and can be upgraded to support other tags. Good luck @holographix

Comment: If you are interested, I add a recursive function to solve this and it works just with cheerio. @holographix

Comment: this example removes all unaffected <li> elements with latest version of cheerio

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution:

This is the code that does it by iterating all dom text nodes:

```js
const $ = require('cheerio').load(inputHtml);
const getTextNodes=(elem)=>elem.type==='text'?[]:
        elem.contents().toArray()
        .filter(el=>el!==undefined)//I don't know why some elements are undefined
        .reduce((acc, el)=>
            acc.concat(...el.type==='text'?[el]:getTextNodes($(el))), [] )
    
    
const replaceRegex = /ipsum/g;
const replacementTag =  `<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a>`;

getTextNodes($(`html`))
    .filter(node=>$.html(node).match(replaceRegex))
    .map(node=>$(node).replaceWith($.html(node).replace(replaceRegex,replacementTag))  );

console.log($.html());
```

**Output:**

```html
<html><head></head><body><p>
    Lorem <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porttitor, magna nec sollicitudin varius, ligula nisi finibus nulla, vel posuere libero erat eu tortor.
</p>
<p>
    </p><ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a></li>
        <li>dolor</li>
        <li>sit</li>
        <li>amet</li>
    </ul>
<p></p>
<p>
    Lorem <b><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=ipsum">ipsum</a></b> <span><em>dolor</em></span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p></body></html>
```

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66694282/1555615)